# Tokenizing in pig (using python udf)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, nltk

Here is what i have done to tokenize in pig,
**My pig script**

```
--set the debugg mode
SET debug 'off'
-- Registering the python udf
REGISTER /home/hema/phd/work1/coding/myudf.py USING streaming_python as myudf

RAWDATA =LOAD '/home/hema/temp' USING TextLoader() AS content;
LOWERCASE_DATA =FOREACH RAWDATA GENERATE LOWER(content) AS con;
TOKENIZED_DATA =FOREACH LOWERCASE_DATA GENERATE myudf.special_tokenize(con) as conn;
DUMP TOKENIZED_DATA;
```

**My Python UDF**

```
from pig_util import outputSchema
import nltk

@outputSchema('word:chararray')
def special_tokenize(input):
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(input)
    return tokens
```

The code works fine but the output is messy. How can i remove the unwanted underscrore and vertical bars. The output looks like this

```
(|{_|(_additionalcontext|)_|,_|(_in|)_|,_|(_namefinder|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_is|)_|,_|(_there|)_|,_|(_any|)_|,_|(_possibility|)_|,_|(_to|)_|,_|(_use|)_|,_|(_additionalcontext|)_|,_|(_with|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_namefinderme.train|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_if|)_|,_|(_so|)_|,_|(_,|)_|,_|(_how|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_if|)_|,_|(_there|)_|,_|(_is|)_|,_|(_n't|)_|,_|(_maybe|)_|,_|(_this|)_|,_|(_should|)_|,_|(_be|)_|,_|(_an|)_|,_|(_issue|)_|,_|(_to|)_|,_|(_be|)_|,_|(_added|)_|,_|(_in|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_future|)_|,_|(_releases|)_|,_|(_?|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_i|)_|,_|(_would|)_|,_|(_really|)_|,_|(_greatly|)_|,_|(_appreciate|)_|,_|(_if|)_|,_|(_someone|)_|,_|(_can|)_|,_|(_help|)_|,_|(_(|)_|,_|(_give|)_|,_|(_me|)_|,_|(_some|)_|,_|(_sample|)_|,_|(_code/show|)_|,_|(_me|)_|,_|(_)|)_|,_|(_how|)_|,_|(_to|)_|,_|(_add|)_|,_|(_pos|)_|,_|(_tag|)_|,_|(_features|)_|,_|(_while|)_|,_|(_training|)_|,_|(_and|)_|,_|(_testing|)_|,_|(_namefinder|)_|,_|(_.|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_if|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_incoming|)_|,_|(_data|)_|,_|(_is|)_|,_|(_just|)_|,_|(_tokens|)_|,_|(_with|)_|,_|(_no|)_|,_|(_pos|)_|,_|(_tag|)_|,_|(_information|)_|,_|(_,|)_|,_|(_where|)_|,_|(_is|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_information|)_|,_|(_taken|)_|,_|(_then|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_a|)_|,_|(_new|)_|,_|(_file|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_run|)_|,_|(_a|)_|,_|(_pos|)_|,_|(_tagging|)_|,_|(_model|)_|,_|(_before|)_|,_|(_training|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_or|)_|,_|(_?|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_and|)_|,_|(_what|)_|,_|(_is|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_purpose|)_|,_|(_of|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_resources|)_|,_|(_(|)_|,_|(_i.e|)_|,_|(_.|)_|,_|(_collection.|)_|,_|(_<|)_|,_|(_string|)_|,_|(_,|)_|,_|(_object|)_|,_|(_>|)_|,_|(_emptymap|)_|,_|(_(|)_|,_|(_)|)_|,_|(_)|)_|,_|(_in|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_namefinderme.train|)_|,_|(_method|)_|,_|(_?|)_|,_|(_what|)_|,_|(_should|)_|,_|(_be|)_|,_|(_ideally|)_|,_|(_included|)_|,_|(_in|)_|,_|(_there|)_|,_|(_?|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_i|)_|,_|(_just|)_|,_|(_ca|)_|,_|(_n't|)_|,_|(_get|)_|,_|(_these|)_|,_|(_things|)_|,_|(_from|)_|,_|(_the|)_|,_|(_java|)_|,_|(_doc|)_|,_|(_api|)_|,_|(_.|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_in|)_|,_|(_advance|)_|,_|(_!|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_best|)_|,_|(_,|)_|}_)
(|{_|(_svetoslav|)_|}_)
```

**original data**

```
AdditionalContext in NameFinder 
Is there any possibility to use additionalContext with the NameFinderME.train? If so, how? If there isn't maybe this should be an issue to be added in the future releases?
I would REALLY greatly appreciate if someone can help (give me some sample code/show me)  how to add POS tag features while training and testing NameFinder.
If the incoming data is just tokens with NO POS tag information, where is the information taken then? A new file? Run a POS tagging model before training? Or?
And what is the purpose of the resources (i.e. Collection.<String,Object>emptyMap()) in the NameFinderME.train method? What should be ideally included in there?
I just can't get these things from the Java doc API.
 in advance!
Best,
Svetoslav
```

I would like to have a list of tokens as my final output.thanks in advance.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have posted my original data as edit. i dont think the NLTK is generating the underscore and vertical bars. The same Word_tokenize() method works fine when i execute in the grunt shell.

Comment: Alright, secondary question. What is the output you expect? (and sidenote: you are passing the string to python, so why do additional map-reduce work to lowercase the strings in Pig?)

Comment: i am expecting a tuple of tokenized strings as output. eg('additionalcontext','in','namefinder').Actually i want to do all the preprocessing in pig. The built-in-function (tokenize) in pig doesnt tokenize the way i prefer, Thats why i thought of using NLTK.

Comment: can you explain me why the underscore and vertical bar got inserted?. is the decorator causing this?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, never wrote a Pig UDF in python

Comment: Wow! Yet another level of `NLTK` with `pig`. Interesting... Out of pure curiosity, why do you need `pig`? How much data do you have? Wouldn't parallelized dataframes and `df.apply()` be sufficient (e.g. https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame/issues/16#issuecomment-185326257) ?

Comment: @alvas i am mining the software repositories(chat histories,email archives,bug reports) which is fairly huge. pig makes mining these repositories easy according to this [paper] (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0164121211002007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pig_util import outputSchema
import nltk
import re 

@outputSchema('word:chararray')
def special_tokenize(input):
    #splitting camel-case here
    temp_data = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])'," ",input)
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(temp_data.encode('utf-8'))
    final_token = ','.join(tokens) 
    return final_token
```

There was some problem with the encoding of the input. changing it to utf-8 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE for '_' and '|' and then use TOKENIZE for tokens.

```
NEW_TOKENIZED_DATA =FOREACH TOKENINZED_DATA GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE($0,'_',''),'|','');
TOKENS = FOREACH NEW_TOKENIZED_DATA GENERATE TOKENIZE($0);
DUMP TOKENS;
```

Comment: do you want me to tokenize twice. why are these underscores and verical bars getting into the bag that is returned by the udf. cant this be avoided, instead of replacing them and doing a second round tokenization.

Comment: I am not sure where it is coming from.You could easily tokenize the input to get the tokens instead of the UDF. The script I have posted is for the output you are getting and not for the original data.

Comment: The built in tokenizer doesnt tokenize the text in the way i prefer. Thats why i am using the UDF and NLTK

Comment: then use replace and tokenize again.